# How can I improve my poorly received Stack Overflow question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions

I read the FAQ, googled for insights, looked at possible duplicate questions, tried to tailor my code excerpts to the minimum, but the reception to one of my questions was still not well-received.  If there is any way for me to improve this, I would surely like to know, because I thought I was diligently following proper procedure.

This is the question that resulted in trouble:

[Why is my background image cut off at the bottom by my CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54026527/why-is-my-background-image-cut-off-at-the-bottom-by-my-css)

Can anyone provide insight into why my specific post may have been poorly received?

Comment: I'm not sure why this meta post is receiving such a negative response - poor title aside, this is a well phrased, straightforward request for feedback on a specific question. @Thomas, I hope that you're able to get guidance that's helpful to you. I think this post is a fully appropriate way to seek it.

Comment: I don't think the question was poorly received; it got some downvotes because it was unanswerable as asked, that's all. You asked for help with an HTML background image position without showing the HTML in question. I can certainly see why you might get some downvotes. You have now added the HTML but the downvotes do not magically go away because of that. :(

Comment: "Etiquette" has to do with politeness and similar protocols of behavior and procedure. It is not about "the proper way to ask questions". The proper way to ask questions is what's outlined in e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Etiquette is the wrong term. Etiquette refers to behaviour towards other users. This is about question quality and reception, which is orthogonal to etiquette. A question can be perfectly on-topic, well researched, useful for future readers... and yet breach a number of etiquette rules nonetheless. And one can be perfectly polite and respectful, and yet post a completely off-topic or useless question.

Comment: @matt that comment is an answer.

Comment: @yivi Using "etiquette" and "orthogonal" in the same sentence = +1.

Answer (score 8):

I have provided some feedback in the comments under your question. Mainly, when you have a problem with code that does not work, we absolutely need to see that code. In the case of a web page problem, you did well to include the CSS, but CSS only applies styles to *HTML*, and you did not include said HTML in your post.

Further, one of the more difficult to grok rules here is that such code snippets should be in the form of a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example (MCVE).

- Minimal - code snippets should not include irrelevant details, e.g. font styles are irrelevant to a problem with background-image sizing. Help us help you by only presenting us with the information we need to reproduce your problem.
- Complete - likewise, code snippets should be complete enough that they have the code that includes the problem. We often see questions where someone will include some function or partial code snippet, and the first few comments will say something like 'this clearly indicates that your problem is somewhere else... in a file or function you have not shared'. We can't solve a problem with half the equation missing.
- Verifiable - the snippet has to reproduce the issue you've described. Sometimes you'll find you've just got a transcription error/typo, or maybe the error occurs for you but not for us... perhaps because of the browser you're using, or some cached file, or some other thing that's not immediately obvious. Make sure your example verifies and reproduces your problem.

It is likely that your question was downvoted for lacking these things. Luckily, your question has been edited to include these things, at least partially.

Continue responding to criticism/questions in the comments and editing your question to improve it and you will see less negative reception to your questions over time. No guarantees that *this* question will get turned around, score-wise (many people vote and then never return to a question, especially if they vote down), but it is certainly possible.